# asp.net code behind and javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, code-behind

I have two scripts called from two different onclick events in my codebehind. I guess it was working properly but now one of my function is not getting called. I am using following way for calling my script functions :

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "hwa", "ShowPopup1('" + PopUpContent +     "');", true);

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "hwa", "ShowPopUp();", true);
```

First one is getting called. But when I click on second button alert in second script does not popup.

Comment: both scripts have the same key...

Comment: @SteveB I have changed the key but still the same result.

Comment: Can you paste your aspx code for us?

Comment: Any errors in the JS console?